# List<string> items to string

Tags: c#

I wanted to ask if it's possible to change List items to one string?

```
List<string> example = new List<string>();
example.Add("1");
example.Add("2");
example.Add("3");
string text = "123";
```

Comment: You should try to find a solution before you ask a question. Btw, you could also use `string.Concat(example)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) is for you

```
string s = string.Join("", example )
```